# I'm not getting any other ideas to solve this problem thr question is a bit lengthy so its mentioned below with what ive tried

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given any four positive, distinct, real numbers, show that one can choose three numbers A, B, C among them, such that all the quadratic equations have only real roots or all of them have only imaginary roots. Bx+x+C=0; C²+x+A=0;
Ax²+x+B=0.

I found this question in Pathfinder senior

In this question i have only approach that is to use discriminants of quadratic and make cases if the given numbers are less that or more than 1 but Using this approach it's not quite easy in some cases to conclude while in some cases you will find it very easy to conclude things like when all are greater than 1

Comment: Please make the title related to the content of the question. It's also not clear what exactly you are asking. You mention four numbers but only use three. Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discriminants of those quadratics are $1-4BC$, $1-4AC$, and $1-4AB$ respectively. That means we basically just care whether the products $AB, BC, AB$ are $\le \frac 1 4$ (real roots) vs $> \frac 1 4$ (imaginary roots).

Let $p, q, r, s$ be the four numbers we're choosing from, ordered like $0 < p  \le q \le r \le s$. Then:

- If $qr \le \frac 1 4$, we can choose $(A,B,C) = (p,q,r)$. That's because $pr$ and $pq$ are both $ \le qr \le \frac 1 4$, so all 3 discriminants will be nonnegative, giving only real roots for all 3 quadratics.
- Otherwise, we must have $qr > \frac 1 4$. In this case, we can choose $(A,B,C) = (q,r,s)$. We know $qs$ and $rs$ are both $\ge qr > \frac 1 4$, so this time we get negative discriminants for all three quadratics, meaning all 3 have only imaginary roots.

---

In that proof, we should note the importance of the assumption $p,q,r,s \ge 0$. The argument hinges on the fact that if $qr \le \frac 1 4$ and $p \le q \le r$ then $pq \le \frac 1 4$. This reasoning would fail if we allowed negative inputs though: think about $p = -1000, q = -1, r = 1$ where $qr = 1 < \frac 1 4$ but $pq = 1000 > \frac 1 4$.

In fact, the overall claim will fail if we were allowed to choose negatives. If the four available numbers are $-1, -1, 1, 1$, then no matter which $A,B,C$ we choose, it'll always be possible to represent both $-1$ and $1$ as products of two numbers from $A,B,C$, which means there'll always be at least one quadratic with all imaginary roots and at least one with all real roots.